# Unable to pass parameter from the api request to outside

Tags: mocha.js, supertest

The code below is a simple mocha test where I am trying to pass the value of the variable my_token  so that I can use in different tests.  Tried all the possibilities but its not working. Not sure what I am doing wrong!

```
var supertest = require('supertest'),
    api = supertest('www.xyz.com');

    var my_token = 'DID NOT WORK';

    describe('get collars list', function(done) {   

        before(function(done) {
            api.post('/api/v2/auth')
                .send({username:"SP",password:"**"})
                .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
                .expect(200)
                .end(function (err, res) {                  

                my_token = "worked"

                done();
            });
            console.log ('passing value to the test :  '+ my_token );
        });  

     it('should login', function(done) {     
       console.log (' token passed to test  : ' + my_token);
     });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need `done` in a test case that doesn't involve asynchronous operation.

This should work.

```
var supertest = require("supertest"),
  api = supertest("www.xyz.com");

var my_token = "DID NOT WORK";

describe("get collars list", function(done) {
  before(function(done) {
    api
      .post("/api/v2/auth")
      .send({ username: "SP", password: "**" })
      .set("Content-Type", "application/json")
      .expect(200)
      .end(function(err, res) {
        my_token = "worked";

        done();
      });
    console.log("passing value to the test :  " + my_token);
  });

  it("should login", function() {
    console.log(" token passed to test  : " + my_token);
  });
});
```

Comment: It throws the following error if done is removed -  Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves. (C:\projects\es-stack\apitests2\test\hello.js)

Comment: Only remove `done` from the `it("should login")` part.